# Is it possible to use context processors in Django without a request object?

Tags: django

The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) describes the use of context processors when you have a request instance -- typical usage is to use `RequestContext` instead of `Context` when rendering a template.

But what if you want context processors, but are not operating within the request/response cycle?  An example use case is rendering templates in response to signals or management commands for email reports.  It's very inconvenient to have to either pre-render any content within a request cycle (and thus lose the advantage of loose-coupling that signals provide), or to have to manually invoke the context, such as "site", for every render invocation.

Is there a way to get the default context processors when there is no `request` instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can get what they *are* via `...settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`, but you can't *use* them since you need a request instance in order to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If rendering your templates requires the request, why not pass that in as the `sender` param when sending the signal

```
def my_view(request):
    my_signal.send(sender=request, foo=True)
    return HttpResponse("YadaYadaYada")
```